# How to convert miliseconds to datetime with format: mm:ss:msmsms (minutes:seconds:miliseconds) without year , month an day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Is there a simple way to convert milliseconds in a dataframe to a datetime without year, month and day?

I have successfully converted a column of milliseconds to datetime. However, I want to get rid of the year, months and days.

I did this:

```
df['Laptimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['milliseconds'], unit='ms')
```

But my values are now formatted as: `"1970-01-01 00:01:38.109"`.

I want to have: `"01:38:109"`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime and https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Just call the time() method on the datetime object:

```
df['Laptimes'].time()
```